# Checkbox to act like radio button, check first four or last four checkboxes but not both- javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am having a problem in javaScript. 
I want to check either any of the first 4 checkboxes or any of the last four checkboxes to true. 
here in my code if i check any one of the first four or all first four of the checkbox, last four checkboxes are disabled. 
now after checking any one or the first four last four are unclickable.
i want them to be clickable and the first four checkboxes to be unchecked.
please correct my code

Here is my code and thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FooBar</title>
<script language="javascript">
function checkOnly(checked)
{
  if(document.myForm.elements[0].checked == true || document.myForm.elements[1].checked == true || document.myForm.elements[2].checked == true || document.myForm.elements[3].checked == true)
  {
      document.myForm.elements[4].checked = 0;
      document.myForm.elements[5].checked = 0;
      document.myForm.elements[6].checked = 0;
      document.myForm.elements[7].checked = 0;
  }  


}        
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<?php for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){ ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
<?php } ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the the 'checked' parameter of you checkOnly function to determine which checkbox the user checked (maybe give them unique ids).  As your logic stands now, if you check the first checkbox, it will clear out the checkboxes on the last four.  Then if you check the last checkbox, it will still clear out the last four checkboxes ***because the first checkbox is still checked***.  This makes it look like the last four checkboxes are disabled even though they aren't.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FooBar</title>
<script language="javascript">
function checkOnly(myCheckbox) {
   var checkboxChanged = false;
   var checkedTotalValue = 0;
   var changedTotalValue = 0;

   for(var i = 0; i < document.myForm.elements.length; i++) {
      if(document.myForm.elements[i].name != myCheckbox.name) {
         if(document.myForm.elements[i].checked == true) {
            checkboxChanged = true;
            changedTotalValue += parseInt(document.myForm.elements[i].value);
         }
         document.myForm.elements[i].checked = false;
      }

      if(document.myForm.elements[i].checked == true) {
        checkedTotalValue += parseInt(document.myForm.elements[i].value);
      }
   }

   if(checkboxChanged) {
      alert('Checked: ' + checkedTotalValue + ', Changed: ' + changedTotalValue);
   }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup1" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup1" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup1" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup1" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup2" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup2" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup2" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup2" id="cb" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to get an alert when all the checked checkbox are unchecked.

Comment: You are awesome man.... thanks for the answer, but how to get an alert when all the checked checkbox are unchecked. for example if you select 4th checkbox and then select 5th checkbox. i need to get an alert or if i select 8th checkbox and then select any one of the first 4 i need to get alert.  And add all the checked checkbox value.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but I updated the example.  Hopefully that helps, or at least gives you an idea of how to approach your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Got my answer