# php html java checkbox array, but have first 4 act like radio

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I've been playing with trying to get the first 4 of a checkbox array to act like radio buttons for a while now and I thought I had it but I can't figure it out.. I searched through here and found..
[Checkbox to act like radio button, check first four or last four checkboxes but not both- javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657356/checkbox-to-act-like-radio-button-check-first-four-or-last-four-checkboxes-but)

Though I've haven't quite been able to make it work in my case apparently. So to re-iterate. I need the first 4 you can only pick 1, while the others can be multiple of any combination. I know its something small I have to be missing.

HTML

```
 <form name="account_info" id="account_info">
 <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="0" onClick="checkOnly(this)"> Permission 0<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="1" onClick="checkOnly(this)"> Permission 1<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="2" onClick="checkOnly(this)"> Permission 2<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="3" onClick="checkOnly(this)"> Permission 3<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="4"> Permission 4<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="5"> Permission 5<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="6"> Permission 6<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="7"> Permission 7<br>
 </form>
```

The Script

```
function checkOnly(myCheckbox) {
   for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(document.account_info.elements[i].name != myCheckbox.name) {
         document.account_info.elements[i].checked = false;
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/np4dry0f/3/

Comment: Yes, just make them into radio buttons. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `name` attribute will always be `permissions[]` in javascript.

A possible solution is to use the value instead of the name:

```
function checkOnly(myCheckbox) {
   for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(document.account_info.elements[i].value != myCheckbox.value) {
         document.account_info.elements[i].checked = false;
      }
   }
}
```

See an example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/vejajaxaxeju/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: I knew it was something simple. I couldn't for the life of me figure out why. I was certain it put the permissions[0], permissions[1] etc etc. Thank you so much for the clarification. I got to learn something too

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than looping through each checkbox

```js
$('.radio').change(function() {
  $('.radio').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
  $(this).attr('checked','checked');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="account_info" id="account_info">
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="0"> Permission 0<br>
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="1"> Permission 1<br>
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="2"> Permission 2<br>
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="3"> Permission 3<br>
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="4"> Permission 4<br>
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="5"> Permission 5<br>
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="6"> Permission 6<br>
<input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="7"> Permission 7<br>
</form>
```